# xlToRight but NOT include first columns

Tags: excel, vba

```
Worksheets("front").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
```

already have this code down, works great - problem is .. I dont want it to fill in column A, which happens to be blank, so code is working as intended, I need it to skip over and to start taking the next available column AFTER column H... I tried working with some offsetting but was still not able to get it to do what I need.

Any help greatly appreciated! Seems the resources on xlright isnt as common asn xlup :)

```
Worksheets("front").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
```

Comment: I guess you want to use End(xlToLeft) insetad of End(xlToRight)

Comment: Think about it for a second and ask yourself what the `End property` does: it mimics `Ctrl + one of the arrow keys`. If you have referenced the last cell in row 5 (`.Cells(5, Columns.Count)` e.g. `XFD5`), which arrow key do you need to use?

Answer (score 0):

you could be after this;

```
Option Explicit

Function GetFirstAvailableColumnIndexAfterColumnH(sh As Worksheet) As Long

    With sh               
        GetFirstAvailableColumnIndexAfterColumnH = WorksheetFunction.Max(8, .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) + 1
    End With

End Function
```

to test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Worksheets("front")

    sh.Cells(5, GetFirstAvailableColumnIndexAfterColumnH(sh)).Value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: Wasn't able to get that to work - I may be giving an illusion that I know more than I do. In the grade scheme, what I am trying to accomplish is from an inputbox it doing a WHOLE lot of things - one of which is putting today's date in the furthest to the right colmun within row 5, starting from cloumn H. So as of now, there is data in column H through column N, and when I run this macro I want it to put today's date in column O, then next time it is ran, put into column P and so on.. Sorry if my original question didn't include that part

Comment: just edited my answer in the "test()" sub to print the date in row 5 next available column after column H

Answer (score 0):

### First 'Available' Cell in Row

... i.e. the cell adjacent to the right of the rightmost non-empty cell

**Using the End Property**

- Keep in mind that this will fail if the column of the 'last' cell is hidden (give it a test so it'll sink in). If that's a possibility, rather use the Find method version.

```vb
Sub AddTodayEnd()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Front")
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("H5")
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.Cells(fCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    If lCell.Column < fCell.Column Then Set lCell = fCell
    lCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Date
End Sub
```

**Using the Find Method (Recommended)**

```vb
Sub AddTodayFind()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Front")
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("H5")
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = fCell.Resize(, ws.Columns.Count _
        - fCell.Column + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Set lCell = fCell
    lCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Date
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
'col is the column index of the first column avaible to you
Dim col As Long
col = Worksheets("front").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If (col < 8) Then
    col = 8
Else
    col = col + 1
End If
Worksheets("front").Cells(5, col).Value = "Your Data"
```